# undefined parameter received in Bixby function

Tags: bixby

I'm trying to process an utterance in the format "Get News from Impeachment Sage" where Impeachment Sage corresponds to an enum of publication names.  Bixby is successfully understanding the utterance and trying to call my goal (GetNewsByName) but the trained Value is not arriving at the function. (This is based off the user persistence data example).

[image]

The operative portion of the function is thus:

```
function getNewsByName(altBrainsNames) {
  // const name = "Impeachment Sage" //hard coded for testing

  const url = properties.get("config", "baseUrl") + "altbrains"
  console.log("i got to restdb.js and the url is ", url);
  console.log("AltBrainsNames is", altBrainsNames)
  const query = {
    apikey: properties.get("secret", "apiKey"),
     q: "{\"" + "name" + "\":\"" + name + "\"}"
    // q: "{}"
  }
  console.log("query", query)
  const options = {
    format: "json",
    query: query,
    cacheTime: 0
  }
  const response = http.getUrl(url, options) 
  if (response) {
    const content1 = response
    // const altBrainsData = response[0][properties.get("config", "altbrainsName")]
    // altbrainsData.$id = response[0]["_id"]
    console.log('content1', content1);
    console.log('identifier', content1)
    return content1
  } else {
    // Doesn't exist
    console.log('doesnae exist');
    return
  }
}
```

What is happening here where the Value is not reaching the function?

The Action model is:

```
action (GetNewsByName) {
  description ("Get news  data from remote Content db by searching on AltBrain name")
  type (Calculation)
  output (Content)
  collect {
   input (altBrainsNames) {
      type (AltBrainsNames)
      min (Required) max (One) //this means js must catch error when multiple names offered

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved this offline, just wanted to follow up on the public channel to any fellow Bixby developers seeing this question posted.  The function that calls 'getNewsByName' needs to receive the input parameter.  Once populated, the action worked successfully.  [image]

[image]